# Strace file output in restricted folder

Tags: strace

I am trying to use strace to debug a program in a directory that I only have execute access to.

Since it's multithreaded, I'd like to use -ff and -o to get the child process traced as well.

So my current command is:

strace -ff -o /bin/ExeOnly/Program1

Obviously this doesn't work since strace then tries to make all the files in that directory, realizes that it doesn't have permission to do so, and fails on me.

How do I make strace create the files in my current directory?

Answer (score 0):

When using `-o` argument in `strace`, you must specify a file name to write the log.  In your case, you could use, for example:

```
strace -ff -o program1-strace.log /bin/ExeOnly/Program1
```

and the file `program1-strace.log` will be created in your working directory with the `strace` output.